# Store Images on server side in android?

Tags: java, android, image, web-services, bitmap

I try to store my images on server and also on SQLite database but the exception is occurred .all other parameters values are stored in the database but the images are not stored.Tell that where I am wrong.

**LogIn.java**

```
    private class Images extends AsyncTask<Bitmap[],Bitmap,Bitmap[]> {

    private Exception exception;

    protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Bitmap[]...urls) {


        try {
            bitmap1 = DownloadImage(mimagelicense);
            bitmap2 = DownloadImage(mauthcard);
            bitmap3= DownloadImage(mpic);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            imageInByte1 = stream.toByteArray();


            System.out.print("DB storing image " + imageInByte1);          

            bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            imageInByte2 = stream.toByteArray();
            bitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            imageInByte3 = stream.toByteArray();

            System.out.println(" ****************************");     

            for(int i = 0; i < driver_details.length; i++) 
                // System.out.println(driver_details[i]);
                Log.v("Async variables",driver_details[i]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        db = new PasswordDB(getApplicationContext());           
        try
        {
            db.insert(mfname, msname, mun, mstreet, msuburb,mstate, mpostcode, mlicense, mid, mmobile, memail,  imageInByte1, imageInByte2, imageInByte3);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Contacts

        //db.close();


        return bitmap;
    }   

    private  java.io.InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException
            {
        java.io.InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
            }                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");           
        }
        return in;    
            }
    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {       
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        java.io.InputStream in = null;       
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;               
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap[] result) 
    {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }


}
private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Config error "+name);
    }
}
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
    }
};

public void gcmService()
{
    checkNotNull(SERVER_URL, "SERVER_URL");

    checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    if (regId.equals(""))
    {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
        } else {
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    boolean registered = ServerUtilities.register(context,
                            regId);
                    if (!registered) {
                        GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    try{
        if (mRegisterTask != null) {
            mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
        }
        if(mHandleMessageReceiver!=null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

            GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

**Registration.java**

```
public class Registration extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText fname,sname,un,street,suburb,password,confirm_password,postcode,license,id,mobile,email,imagelicense,authcard,pic;
String mfname,msname,mun,mstreet,msuburb,mstate,mpassword,mconfirm_password,mpostcode,mlicense,mid,mmobile,memail,mimagelicense,mauthcard,mpic;
Button submit , upload_license, upload_authority,upload_face;
TextView rt;
private Spinner state;
private static MyDialog dialog1;
private Typeface ftype;
private  PasswordDB dp; 
static final int DIALOG_ID = 0;
Uri imageUri;
private Bitmap license_img,authority_img,face_img ;
private static final int PICK_Camera_IMAGE = 2;
private WebView webview1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE1 = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE2 = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE3 = 3;
String regid;
private Context mContext;
static String device_token="";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";

String SENDER_ID = "960152798745";


AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;


static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
//GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;

ImageView license_image,authority_image,face_image;
InputStream iss;
BitmapFactory.Options bfo;
Bitmap bitmapOrg;
ByteArrayOutputStream bao ;
private Bitmap bitmap;
String deviceId;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.registration);

    deviceId = Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    Toast.makeText(this, deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.print("Device Id"+deviceId);



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID is"+deviceId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    Log.v("debiceID",deviceId);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) 
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  

        //  ftype=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/Futura Koyu.ttf");
        fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.efirst_name);

        sname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.esur_name);

        un = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eunit_no);

        street = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.estreet_name);

        suburb = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.esuburb);

        state = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.state);

        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.epassword);

        confirm_password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.econfirm_password);

        postcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.epost_code);

        license = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edriving_license);

        id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eauthority_id);

        mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emobile_no);

        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eemail);

        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        upload_license  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.license);
        upload_authority  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.authority);
        upload_face  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.face);
        license_image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);
        authority_image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic2);
        face_image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic3);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Registration.this, webview.class);

                startActivity(intent);

                new DriverRegistration().execute(); 

                System.out.println("called ");
            }
        });


        String[] mystate= new String[]{"New South Wales","Victoria","Queensland","Northern Territory","Western Australia","South Australia"};       
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Registration.this, R.layout.listrow, mystate);
        state.setAdapter(adapter);  
        state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
                mstate =  state.getSelectedItem().toString();



                String s1=arg0.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                if(s1.equals("New South Wales"))
                    suburb.setText("Sydney");
                else if(s1.equals("Victoria"))
                    suburb.setText("Melbourne");
                else if(s1.equals("Queensland"))
                    suburb.setText("Brisbane");
                else if(s1.equals("Northern Territory"))
                    suburb.setText("Darwin");
                else if(s1.equals("Western Australia"))
                    suburb.setText("Perth");
                else if(s1.equals("South Australia"))
                    suburb.setText("Adelaide");

            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
}



public void pickImage(View View) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE1);
}


public void pickImage2(View View) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE2);
}



public void pickImage3(View View) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE3);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

class RegisterBackground extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    private final Context _context;

    public RegisterBackground(Context context){
        _context = context;

    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String msg = "";
        return regid;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        //mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");

        Registration test =(Registration) _context ;


        device_token=msg;


        super.onPostExecute(msg);

    }
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend(String regid) {

        //String url = "http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php";
        String url = "http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/DGCapp/webservice.php";
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_token", regid));
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         

    }
}

private class DriverRegistration extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Registration.this);
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(final String... params) 
    {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try 
            {

                System.out.println("driver ");

                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait DriverRegistration...");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }
                });

                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                JSONObject job= new JSONObject();

                mfname = fname.getText().toString();
                msname = sname.getText().toString();
                mun= un.getText().toString();
                mstreet = street.getText().toString();
                msuburb = suburb.getText().toString();
                mstate= state.getSelectedItem().toString();
                mpostcode = postcode.getText().toString();
                mlicense =license.getText().toString();
                mid = id.getText().toString();
                mmobile = mobile.getText().toString();
                memail= email.getText().toString();
                mpassword=password.getText().toString();
                mconfirm_password=confirm_password.getText().toString();

                mfname.replace("" ,"%20");
                msname.replace("" ,"%20");
                mun.replace("" ,"%20");
                mstreet.replace("" ,"%20");
                msuburb.replace("" ,"%20");
                mstate.replace("" ,"%20");
                mpostcode.replace("" ,"%20");
                mlicense.replace("" ,"%20");
                mid.replace("" ,"%20");
                mmobile.replace("" ,"%20");
                memail.replace("" ,"%20");
                mpassword.replace("" ,"%20");
                mconfirm_password.replace("" ,"%20");

                //                      
                bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bfo.inSampleSize = 32;

                //bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + customImage, bfo);
                bfo.inScaled = true;
                bfo.inPurgeable = true;

                bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                license_img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bao);

                license_img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(license_img, 200, 200, false);

                byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
                int baa = (ba.length)/1024;

                authority_img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bao);

                authority_img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(license_img, 200, 200, false);
                byte [] baaa = bao.toByteArray();
                int baas = (baaa.length)/1024;

                face_img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bao);
                face_img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bao);
                byte [] baaap = bao.toByteArray();
                int baasp = (baaap.length)/1024;



                System.out.println("size of image ....."+baa);
                //String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
                System.out.println(" imagedata................"+baa);

                String license_img = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

                String authority_img = Base64.encodeBytes(baaa);

                String face_img = Base64.encodeBytes(baaap);


                System.out.println("size of image1 ................."+license_img);
                System.out.println("size of image2 ................."+authority_img);
                System.out.println("size of image3 ................."+face_img);

                job.put("method","driver_register");
                job.put("first_name",mfname);
                job.put("surname",msname);
                job.put("unit_no",mun);
                job.put("street_name",mstreet);
                job.put("suburb",msuburb);
                job.put("state",mstate);
                job.put("password",mpassword);
                //      job.put("mpassword",mconfirm_password);
                job.put("post_code","mpostcode");
                job.put("driving_license",mlicense);
                job.put("authority_id",mid);
                job.put("mobile_no",mmobile);
                job.put("email",memail);
                job.put("device_id",device_token);


                job.put("license_pic",license_img);
                job.put("audit_card_pic",authority_img);

                job.put("face_pic",face_img);
                // job.put("unique_id",androidId);


                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(job.toString());
                //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/mobileapp_now/webservice.php");
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://suntechwebsolutions.com/clients/DGCapp/webservice.php");

                httppost.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String tmpString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                String data = tmpString.replace("yes","");  



                Log.i("response", data);

                System.out.println("response "+data);
                String call;
                call = data;

                System.out.println("print me............."+call);

                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
                Log.d("response", jo.toString(4));

                if(jo.getString("err-code").equals("0"))
                {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) 
                        {

                            pDialog.dismiss();


                            dialog.dismiss();

                            startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this,LoginActivity.class));

                        }
                    });
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Alert !");
                    alert.setMessage(jo.getString("message"));
                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            pDialog.dismiss();

                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registration.this);
            alert.setTitle("Alert !");
            alert.setMessage("No Internet connection ");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                        int whichButton) 
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();


                }
            });
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        }
        return params;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result)
    {
        //
        pDialog.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}   

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {




    switch(requestCode)
    {

    case REQUEST_CODE1:

        resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK ;

        try {
            // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
            if (license_img != null) {
                license_img.recycle();
            }
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
            license_img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            license_image.setImageBitmap(license_img);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        break;

    case REQUEST_CODE2: 

        resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK ;


        try {
            // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
            if (authority_img != null) {
                authority_img.recycle();
            }
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
            authority_img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            authority_image.setImageBitmap(authority_img);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        break;

    case REQUEST_CODE3: 

        resultCode = Activity.RESULT_OK ;


        try {
            // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
            if (face_img != null) {
                face_img.recycle();
            }
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
            face_img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            face_image.setImageBitmap(face_img);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  


    }

}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {

        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}

public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;

    license_img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    authority_img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    face_img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);


    license_image.setImageBitmap(license_img);
    authority_image.setImageBitmap(authority_img);
    face_image.setImageBitmap(face_img);




}


}
```

**Log Cat**

```
       java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /uploads/lic_55.png
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.OpenHttpConnection(LoginActivity.java:511)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.DownloadImage(LoginActivity.java:542)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:460)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-11 07:42:29.002: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /uploads/card_55.png
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.OpenHttpConnection(LoginActivity.java:511)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.DownloadImage(LoginActivity.java:542)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:461)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-11 07:42:29.012: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /uploads/face_55.png
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.OpenHttpConnection(LoginActivity.java:511)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.DownloadImage(LoginActivity.java:542)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:462)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:464)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at com.sunmobileappnow.mobileappnow.LoginActivity$Images.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-11 07:42:29.022: W/System.err(1639):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
```

Comment: read your error message, please.

Comment: how you are storing the images in SQLITE Database?

Comment: You are trying to access the relative path `/uploads/lic_55.png` rather than your full path. Specify the path as *http://example.com/path/uploads/lic_55.png*